# Socket connection error with GAE 1.7.2

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sockets, configuration

I've just updated my application to the latest java GAE SDK 1.7.2 and i have the following error.

```
ATTENTION: /_ah/channel/dev
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 2: Received exception executing http method POST against URL http://127.0.0.1:8888/_ah/channel/connected/: Permission denied: Not allowed to issue a socket connect: permission denied.
        at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.dev.LocalURLFetchService.fetch(LocalURLFetchService.java:398)
        at com.google.appengine.api.channel.dev.ChannelManager.sendChannelPost(ChannelManager.java:283)
        at com.google.appengine.api.channel.dev.ChannelManager.connectClient(ChannelManager.java:221)
        at com.google.appengine.api.channel.dev.LocalChannelServlet.doGet(LocalChannelServlet.java:119)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
        at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:110)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:61)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.BackendServersFilter.doFilter(BackendServersFilter.java:97)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:94)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:380)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

It looks like i have to setup some permission for the use of the channel API with this new version. I can't find any trace of it.

Anyone heard of something like that?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that was introduced in the 1.7.2 dev server.

There is a work-around, see the "filter" work around in the bug.
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8166

Will be fixed in 1.7.3.

p.s. remember to remove the work-around before uploading your app.

Comment: Thx you, i was pretty sure it was a bug introduced with the new release. I hope they will release 1.7.3 soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, read https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#The_Sandbox

Comment: Thx you for your answer but my application works perfectly with the previous versions of GAE SDK. I do not try to open a socket manually, i just use the channel API as it always worked so far :s